# How to add a class onto the selected li element and make li full-sized-clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a class to the selected 'li' and at the same time, remove the class:selected from previous selected li element.

I have worked on it hours and still haven't got any luck. I also checked others questions, but their solutions don't work for me.

Help please....

```
<ul id='mainView' class='menu' style='float: left; clear: both;'>      
    <a href="/Link1"><li>Patient</li></a>
    <a href="/Link2"><li>Recommendations</li></a>

</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.menu ul a').on('click', function (event) {
            $('.menu ul a.selected').className = '';
            alert($(this).attr('id'));
            $(this).attr('class') = 'selected';
        });
    });

//    $('.menu li').on('click', function () {
//        $('.menu li.selected').className = '';
//        this.className = 'selected';
//    });
</script>
```

**Update:**

I did put a inside li, but if I click on the li not the a inside of the li, the webpage does not redirect. That's the reason why I do it in a reversed way.

**Update 2**
The reason why the selected li does not get the "selected" class is because the whole webpage is redirected to a new page which has the same navigation bar.
So now the question is how to highlight the selected li(it was selected on the previous page) on the new webpage.

Comment: Get a good jQuery reference!

Comment: Not the cause of your issues, but the HTML is invalid. The `<a>` elements should be inside the `<li>`s, not wrapping them.

Comment: @bfavaretto thx for your reply. but if I put the a inside the li, then when I click on the li the webpage doesn't redirects. Any idea to solve it?(I want to put a inside li as well.)

Comment: You can bind the event to the li and redirect from js. But what is the point of changing the classes on the As if you're redirecting anyway? After the redirect, the classes won't persist.

Comment: @bfavaretto, you are right, after being redirected the class won't persist, so how can I still hightlight the selected li on the new page?

Comment: I usually deal with that on the server side.

Comment: Or use Ajax to load content into just some part of the page, instead of redirecting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside an `UL` everybody (even a browser) is expecting to see a `LI`

so your HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/Link1">Patient</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Link2">Recommendations</a></li>   
</ul>
```

And your jQ:

```
$('ul li').click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});
```

Building web pages you should know how to treat `LI` elements. Simple, like dummy containers with minimal styling. 
That means that you rather add a `display:block` ... `float:left` and other cool stuff to the `<A>` elements, than setting a `padding` there you go with your **full-sized-clickable** `A` elements.

---

Additionally (if you don't have time to play with CSS) to make a `LI` **fully clickable** use:

```
$('ul li').click(function(){
  var goTo = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
  window.location = goTo ;
  // $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected'); // than you don't need this :D
});
```

### After the OP late edit - and to answer the question

After the pages refreshes **to get which one is the active one** use:

```
// ABSOLUTE PATH
var currentPage = window.location;

// RELATIVE PATH
//  var currentPage = window.location.pathname;

$('li a[href="'+ currentPage +'"]').addClass('selected');
```

Comment: Hi roXon, thank you for your reply. I did it in your way, but if I click on the li not the a inside of the li, the webpage does not redirect.

Comment: @Franva IF you need to redirect than I see no sense of setting a link to `selected`, or you do? If the page refreshes (redirect) you need other nice fancy methods to get the `current` link.

Comment: hi I have changed the order of the li and the a elemtns. As to how to make the full-sized-clickable li elemtns , I cannot understand what you mean, sorry.

Comment: @Franva I mean that the `li` elements should NOT have any `padding` but instead the `A` elements (+ display:block; float:left;) That way the `A` elements will be styled instead of the `LI` ones. Logically if the `A` elements cover the desired width/height you have a bigger clickable area. Makes sense? any way I added a code how to make your `LI` clickable and how to get the `.selected` on the `A` AFTER the pages reload. Hope all that mess helps.

Comment: Hi roXon, great job! the highlight stuff works now. But the li is not full-sized-clickable...

Comment: @Franva if you used this code it HAS to be: `$('ul li').click(function(){
  var goTo = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
  window.location = goTo ;
  // $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected'); // than you don't need this :D
});`

Comment: btw, instead of window.location = goTo ; I use window.location.pathname = goTo ; Cheers roXon :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.menu ul a').on('click', function (event) {
            $('.menu ul a.selected').removeClass('selected');
            alert($(this).attr('id'));
            $(this).addClass('selected')
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [`removeClass`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/), they're jQuery functions:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.menu ul a').on('click', function (event) {
        $('.menu ul a.selected').removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
});
```

Comment: Try changing your HTML structure so that your a tags are **within** the li tags.